# Using Codeigniter Form Validation with Jquery serialize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

I want to use form validation methods of CI for validating my input data. As the form submitted via AJAX I'm using `serializeArray()` to post data to my controller so I don't have to post on by one data or wrinting some `each()` function. The problem is that form validation look for data in $_POST. Using `serialize()` didn't help neither. Is there any solution beside extending form validation library?

here my code:
(controller)

```
$form_data = $this->input->post('form_data');

$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('p_company_name', 'نام شرکت', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
  echo "fail";die(); // if i use serialize() or serializeArray()
}
else
{
  echo "success";die(); // if i use label:value for each form input
}
```

js code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: url,
    data: {'form_data': form_data},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(res, textStatus, xhr) 
    {
        //  do something
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError)
    {
        //do something else
    },
    complete: function()
    {
        // do some final thing
    },
    async: true
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

post your data as:

```
data: form.serialize(),
```

and it will work as normal (form being a normal jquery reference to your page form, not just the word "form")

Comment: Thanks @jmadsen but as I told I tested serialize and it still give me error. That I think because serialze() make the form a query string but nothing that can be understandable by $_POST. for example if I have 2 form element it becomes name1=value1&name2=value2 and will be put in $_POST['form_data']. So when codeigniter search for $_POST["name1"], the result will be false.

Comment: why is it going in form_data? it should just be going into POST vars as normal

in your controller, do a var_dump($_POST) and see what's going on

Comment: `form_data = $("myform").serialize()`. As it's stated in jquery website `serialize` "Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.". It means that after you call this function and assign it to some variable in data property of Ajax, it's just include a `query string`. You can see the example here [http://api.jquery.com/serialize/]. using `var_dump` also shows something like string(n) name1=value1&name2=value2&...

Comment: Don't assign it to a variable, just pass it as your data: part of the ajax call; that's what's causing your problem. You aren't passing serialize(), you're passing a string, and you don't want that

Comment: This is my actual data part of $ajax: `data: {'url':url, 'token': $.cookie('token'), 'command': 'add_new', content_type: 'html', 'form_data': form_data},`. So I have more than one data to pass so I used json notationfor that. how can I change it to something understandable?

Comment: I'm waiting for your response

Comment: read the answer I already gave you, and look around on the web a bit, please